# Regex for finding float numbers in a comma separated string

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am have a csv file that has comma separated line something like this:

```
"22.0,asc1.0$*xyz,12.00,12.00023000,,1.0asc1.0,,-12.4442,0.00000,5.2E-5\n"
```

I want to find all floating point numbers only.

Challenges:

- "asc1.0$*xyz" - string that has decimal but prefix/suffix with non digits should be ignored
- "5.2E-5" - Exponential form should be treated as good result
- Should work for first Item that starts without a comma and last item that ends without a comma.

This expression correctly captures the float part but doesn't work with above scenarios correctly:

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

Thanks in advance!

Complete Code in python (based on the feedback below):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = {"a": 1.0, "b": "xyz.2.0", "c": "lol"}

buffer = StringIO()

df = pd.DataFrame([data])
df.to_csv(buffer, index=False)
input_ = buffer.getvalue()
print(input_)

import re

expression = "(?<=,|^)[+-]?\d+\.?\d*(?:E[+-]?\d+)?(?=,|$)"

def transform_float(m):
    value = m.group()
    print(value)
    return value

result = re.sub(expression, transform_float, input_)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with look arounds:

```
(?:(?<=,)|(?<=^))[+-]?\d+\.?\d*(?:E[+-]?\d+)?(?=,|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/itemOw/2)

**RegEx Description:**

- `(?:(?<=,)|(?<=^))`: Lookbehind to assert that we have a comma or line start at previous position
- `[+-]?\d+\.?\d*(?:E[+-]?\d+)?`: Match an integer or floating point number with **optional** `E` part
- `(?=,|$)`: Lookahead to assert that we have a comma or line end ahead

Comment: What about the `\n`-line feed

Comment: If we are using `MULTILINE` mode then `\n` is handled by `$` anchor.

Comment: Beware that this matches also `1.E1` and *"non-floated"* numbers `11`

Comment: I mentioned in answer also that it matches `an integer or floating point number`

Comment: OK but I just cannot make sense `1.E1` being a valid *exp* number

Comment: @anubhava when i am trying this with multiple lines i get the error "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern" - any clues?

Comment: @user1707312 Python, huh? You should **always** mention the language in interest when asking regexp questions.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes i am trying to do it in python. sorry about the confusion. i am trying to paste a snippet of the actual code if i can figure out the formatting in the comment section

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan- updated the question with the python code.

Comment: @anubhava 

Wait its not working meaning there is no error but i don't get any matches also

Comment: Python regex engine considers `(?<=,|^)` s variable length lookbehind since `^` is zero width assertion. That's why this work-around `(?:(?<=,)|(?<=^))` is needed there.

Comment: @anubhava updated my comment above but seems like there is no error any more but it is not finding any match as well.

Comment: yes! i was missing flags=re.MULTILINE part. Thanks @anubhava

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: `1.E1` is a valid number in `python` (and in may more languages). `print (1.E1)` outputs `10.0`